# STEP UP TRANSFORMER FOR A BICYCLE DYNAMO

Tags: voltage

the thickness of the coil making turns of transformers have to differ. now that the thickness is increased to reduce resistance for step-down transformer where current increases, why cant the same thickness be used on low current since it will be low current against low resistance from the thick coils?

Comment: they have to differ? why?

Answer (score 3):

The thickness of turns does not *have* to differ.

However, you get best efficiency when the volume of copper dedicated to a winding is proportional to the power throughput of that winding. For a transformer with only one secondary, this tends to mean the primary and secondary are roughly equal volume.

If one has a lower current, that means a higher voltage, so more turns of thinner wire. But only tends to be, no compulsion, other than commercial.